# Can't get value from value stack in struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2, ognl

I use struts 2 ,and I want to use struts tag.
I want to use

```
<s:select list="types" name="list"/>
```

to get a list from the value stack,Here is my action code

```
    ValueStack valueStack = ServletActionContext.getContext().getValueStack();
    valueStack.pop();
    valueStack.push(types);
```

But it didn't work.Here is the error message

```
HTTP Status 500 - tag 'select', field 'list', name 'list': The requested list key '#types' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]
```

However if I put the list into the requestScope.It did work,like this`<s:select list="types" name="#request.types"/>`

So what should I do?

Comment: You should rather have a getTypes() method in your action class instead of working directly with the value stack.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just did as you told, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Walid said, i should have a getTypes() method in your action class instead of working directly with the value stack.

So I changed my code like this:

```
List<String> types ;

public List<String> getTypes() {
    return types;
}

types = dailyNewsService.getAllTypes();
```

For a succesful living, implement Preparable Interface and load there your "static" data:

```
@Override
public void prepare() throws Exception {
    types = dailyNewsService.getAllTypes();
}
```